# React Native impossible to get access to a sandbox in 4G but work in Wifi

Tags: react-native, rest, websocket, sandbox, 4g

I have a weird issue, I got a sandbox wss://v2.sandbox and https://v2.sandbox links every request on the API Rest, and the socket server works fine in Wifi but when I want to try the App in 4g no a single request work. Same behavior with my browser, impossible to get access to the dashboard, API rest, or socket server with a shared connexion but work in wifi.

I checked the banip list - clear
I checked my DNS - clear (using the DNS of Google)

My partner who made the BO think that could be the app but I test several free APIs, socket servers anything works still no access to his BO.

I would appreciate some idea on this issue that is out of my spec.
I'm using a Fresh install of RN
I test both fetch API and Axios same results.
RN Version: RN 63.4

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved it was DNS Propagation issue with ip